# Help: area code download in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, evi

I need help exporting this data. I don't know how to make the line of code to download.

I think the error is in `image: s2,`, right?

Code:

```
var addEVI = function (image) {
  var EVI = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8').divide(1000),
      'RED': image.select('B4').divide(1000),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(1000)
    }).rename('EVI');
  return image.addBands(EVI);
};

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2021-09-01', '2021-09-30')
  .map(addEVI);

var palette = ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
  '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
  '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
];

Map.addLayer(s2.median(), {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  bands: ['EVI'],
  palette: palette
}, 'EVI');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: s2,
  description: "evi",
  crs: 'EPSG:3763',
  folder: 'Folder_evi',
  fileNamePrefix: 'evi'
  region: geometry,
  scale: 14,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

Comment: Please use formatted text rather than a screenshot in the body of your question.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Shows this error: Image.setDefaultProjection, argument 'image': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3)

Answer (score 0):

The code works, I had no problem running it *with an extra filter*. Since you didn't filter by region, the code could crash because it's iterating over the whole collection for that date range (thousands of images). Another thing, Sentinel-2's scale factor is 0.0001, not 0.001. So the first function and the image collection definition need small adjustments:

```
var addEVI = function (image) {
  var EVI = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8').divide(10000),
      'RED': image.select('B4').divide(10000),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000)
    }).rename('EVI');
  return image.addBands(EVI);
};

var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2021-09-01', '2021-09-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(addEVI);
```

Comment: Even with the adjustments, it still gives an error when exporting.